# Difference between ‘tagging’ and ‘conjugating’ a fluorochrome to an antibody?

Tags: terminology, antibody

The [Wikipedia entry on fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunofluorescence) repeatedly states that “a fluorochrome must be tagged or conjugated to the antibody”.

How is tagged or conjugated different? Is this a mistake or are these indeed different concepts?

Comment: Your link is a null link.  I'm pretty sure thought that tagging is merely an alternate way of saying the fluorophore is bound to something. Either directly to the macromolecule of interest or "conjugated" first to an antibody that has preference for said molecule of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conjugated and tagged mean the same thing here, although I would advise against using tagged here.

In the context of antibodies, tagging means the addition of a (short) peptide sequence to a protein. Either to do something useful (degradation tag, HHHHHH-tag) or just as an epitope for an antibody.